# Unique key with conditional

Tags: sql, key, conditional-statements, unique

I have table(account_master) with unique key on field (party_code) and i have another field (closed_date). I want unique key with condition, when closed_date is null then party_code can take unique value and when closed_date is not null then field party_code can take duplicate.e.g.

```
party_code   closed_date
 1               null
 2            31-08-2015
 2               null
 3               null
 4               null
```

so how can i apply this unique key to insert data.

Comment: The thing that you have described is not an unique key. Also, it sounds like it belongs to the business logics but not data.

Comment: it is not necessary to apply unique key but there should be any constraint that can full fill this condition on table label in sql orcale

Answer (score 1):

you can use a unique filtered index to solve this problem.

If SQL 2005 then
You could create a schema bound view (select * from account_master where closed_date is null)
and create a unique index on the view...